# how to display fields with header only if they are greater than 0 in crystal reports?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am creating a crystal report from a datatable which has two columns: `cash` and `card`. The datatable is populated via an SQL query.

My report shows correctly, but now I want to change it to only show cash or card entries if they have values (not 0). Otherwise, the field should not show with its header.

For example, if `cash` has a value of `100` and `card` has no value or is 0, then the report shows only the cash entry with its header. If cash and card both have values then both should be display with their headers.

Right now I see this:

```
cash   100
card   0
```

I'd like to see this for the same data:

```
cash   100
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can split the detail section yo Detail a and Detail b (right-click, Insert Section Below). Place the card info in Detail b.

Then, set a dynamic Suppress expression for each section to ensure they don't show if their respective amounts are zero (Value = 0).

Comment: i have placed my column is at report footer b and i suppressed it with formula  if isnull({DataTable1.cash}) or {DataTable1.cash} = "0" then true but it creates blank space at its position and the column which is below not moving upside.that blank space is still there. i have placed columns vertically.